# tksheet and postgresql database (how to update database from tksheet )

Tags: postgresql

I am working with tksheet table which pulls data from postgresql database. The operation I want to perform is to edit the cells from tksheet and get those changes reflected in the database. The treeview update option works but I need to do the same with tksheet to perform update operation from tksheet directly to the database. Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk


def update_records():
my_conn= psycopg2.connect(
host="localhost",
user="postgres",
password="********",
database="TEST4"
)
cursor= my_conn.cursor()
self.sheet.set_sheet_data(data = [[]],
           reset_col_positions = True,
           reset_row_positions = True,
           redraw = True,
           verify = False,
           reset_highlights = False)
cursor.execute('''UPDATE std SET snum, venum, tl, des, stat, ps, lfp, fap, fv, fa fp, pd, ps, uss, ul awg, as, not''')
```

Comment: Please provide table schemas and relevant sql queries to make it easier for the community to answer your question.

Comment: okay sorry for that. I have the table schemas here and the queries here. Thank you!

Comment: I have set the sheet headers with the postgresql table headers and been able to get the table data correctly in the sheet. Now I wanted to update the sheet and get the edited rows in the sheet updated in the database automatically. As with tksheet the data are not in an entry like in the treeview. I am trying to figure out how to get the update database with tksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Facing same question 6 month later, thought this could help someone in the future:

Use the **extra_binding** function to bind the table functionality to your own function which is to update your database. Check the documentation at https://github.com/ragardner/tksheet/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#6-Getting-Table-Data for details (chapter 7).

Answer (score 0):

**Info with Tksheet v 7.**
I added a function to handle the sheet' edits:

```
self.frame.sheet.bind("<<SheetModified>>", updateInv)
```

Then in the function we get the info what and where is edited (then I'm calling a data saving if confirmed correct):

```
def updateInv(event):
        for (x, y), old_value in event.cells.table.items():
```

The x (row) and y (column) will give you the coordinates of the cell that was changed.